# if String is empty then data is not inserting

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server

```
String query = "insert into Odisha_Customer_data([Share _Id], FirstName, MiddleName, LastName, FatherHusbandName, MotherName, "
    + "id,  DOB, Age, CustNatureDesc, [Date of Membership], "
    + "Religion, Nationality, UID, PAN, Segment, IntroducerAccNo, EmpCode, IDproof, IDProofNo, ResidentialProofDesc, ResidentialProofNo, "
    + "AnnualIncomeDetails, [Risk Category of customer], [Closing Bal], Title, gender, category, occupation, community, Qualification, MaritalStatusDesc)"+
    " SELeCT @ShareId, @FirstName, @MiddleName, @LastName, @FatherHusbandName, @MotherName, @id,"
    + "@DOB, @Age, @CustNatureDesc, @DateofMembership, @Religion, @Nationality, @UID, @PAN,"
    + " @Segment, @IntroducerAccNo, @EmpCode, @IDproof, @IDProofNo, @ResidentialProofDesc, @ResidentialProofNo, @AnnualIncomeDetails, @RiskCategoryofcustomer, @ClosingBal," +
    "t.TitleID AS title, g.GenderId AS gender, cat.CatagoryID AS category, o.OccupationID AS Occupation, c.CommunityID AS Community, q.QualificationID AS Qualification," +
    " m.MaritalStatusID AS MaritalStatus FROM Title AS t INNER JOIN Gender AS g ON t.Title = @title INNER JOIN Catagory AS cat ON cat.catagoryname = @Category " +
    "INNER JOIN Occupation AS o ON o.OccupationName = @Occupation INNER JOIN Community AS c ON c.CommunityName = @Community " +
    " INNER JOIN Qualification AS q ON q.QualificationName = @qualification INNER JOIN MaritalStatus AS m ON m.MaritalStatusDesc = @maritalStatusDesc " +
    "WHERE @title Is Not Null AND g.gendername = @Gender AND @Category Is Not Null AND @Occupation Is Not Null " +
    "AND @Community Is Not Null AND @qualification Is Not Null AND @maritalStatusDesc Is Not Null";

//query = "UPDATE a SET a.MaritalStatusDesc = b.MaritalStatusID From Odisha_Customer_data AS a INNER JOIN MaritalStatus AS b ON b.MaritalStatusDesc = '" + MaritalStatusDesc + "' where a.rowid = (Select max(rowid) as NewCustomer from Odisha_Customer_data)";

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);

cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@title", string.IsNullOrEmpty(Title) ? (object)DBNull.Value : Title));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Gender", string.IsNullOrEmpty(gender) ? (object)DBNull.Value : gender));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Occupation", string.IsNullOrEmpty(occupation) ? (object)DBNull.Value : occupation));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Category", string.IsNullOrEmpty(category) ? (object)DBNull.Value : category));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Community", string.IsNullOrEmpty(community) ? (object)DBNull.Value : community));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@qualification", string.IsNullOrEmpty(Qualification) ? (object)DBNull.Value : Qualification));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@maritalStatusDesc", string.IsNullOrEmpty(MaritalStatusDesc) ? (object)DBNull.Value : MaritalStatusDesc));

cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ShareId", string.IsNullOrEmpty(ShareId) ? (object)DBNull.Value : ShareId));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@FirstName", string.IsNullOrEmpty(FirstName) ? (object)DBNull.Value : FirstName));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@MiddleName", string.IsNullOrEmpty(MiddleName) ? (object)DBNull.Value : MiddleName));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@LastName", string.IsNullOrEmpty(LastName) ? (object)DBNull.Value : LastName));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@FatherHusbandName", string.IsNullOrEmpty(FatherHusbandName) ? (object)DBNull.Value : FatherHusbandName));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@MotherName", string.IsNullOrEmpty(MotherName) ? (object)DBNull.Value : MotherName));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@id", string.IsNullOrEmpty(id) ? (object)DBNull.Value : id));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@DOB", string.IsNullOrEmpty(DOB) ? (object)DBNull.Value : DOB));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Age", string.IsNullOrEmpty(Age) ? (object)DBNull.Value : Age));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@CustNatureDesc", string.IsNullOrEmpty(CustNatureDesc) ? (object)DBNull.Value : CustNatureDesc));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@DateofMembership", string.IsNullOrEmpty(DateofMembership) ? (object)DBNull.Value : DateofMembership));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Religion", string.IsNullOrEmpty(Religion) ? (object)DBNull.Value : Religion));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Nationality", string.IsNullOrEmpty(Nationality) ? (object)DBNull.Value : Nationality));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@UID", string.IsNullOrEmpty(UID) ? (object)DBNull.Value : UID));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@PAN", string.IsNullOrEmpty(PAN) ? (object)DBNull.Value : PAN));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Segment", string.IsNullOrEmpty(Segment) ? (object)DBNull.Value : Segment));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@IntroducerAccNo", string.IsNullOrEmpty(IntroducerAccNo) ? (object)DBNull.Value : IntroducerAccNo));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@EmpCode", string.IsNullOrEmpty(EmpCode) ? (object)DBNull.Value : EmpCode));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@IDproof", string.IsNullOrEmpty(IDproof) ? (object)DBNull.Value : IDproof));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@IDProofNo", string.IsNullOrEmpty(IDProofNo) ? (object)DBNull.Value : IDProofNo));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ResidentialProofDesc", string.IsNullOrEmpty(ResidentialProofDesc) ? (object)DBNull.Value : ResidentialProofDesc));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ResidentialProofNo", string.IsNullOrEmpty(ResidentialProofNo) ? (object)DBNull.Value : ResidentialProofNo));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@AnnualIncomeDetails", string.IsNullOrEmpty(AnnualIncomeDetails) ? (object)DBNull.Value : AnnualIncomeDetails));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@RiskCategoryofcustomer", string.IsNullOrEmpty(RiskCategoryofcustomer) ? (object)DBNull.Value : RiskCategoryofcustomer));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ClosingBal", string.IsNullOrEmpty(ClosingBal) ? (object)DBNull.Value : ClosingBal));

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
```

My full code is this and i just want where String value like title,gender etc are empty then will save Null in DB table. But using this code, whenever String value like title, gender etc is empty then data is not inserting. And if all string have value then data save perfectly. Please see the code and correct me.

Comment: That's how `inner joins` works - read about other joins types

Comment: You should really try to make good use of whiteslace too. That code is really difficult to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got multiple problems here. One, as pointed out in the comments, is that INNER JOIN cannot join to NULL (no join can, actually, but read on..) so where, for example you write in your SQL:

```
INNER JOIN MaritalStatus AS m ON m.MaritalStatusDesc = @maritalStatusDesc
```

And then you write in your code:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@maritalStatusDesc", string.IsNullOrEmpty(MaritalStatusDesc) ? (object)DBNull.Value : MaritalStatusDesc));
```

If marital status is blank, your c# will send NULL to the DB (simplification), and for the DB because there is a hard and fast rule that "nothing is ever, ever equal to NULL", that means the JOIN fails. When an inner join fails, it removes the entire row from the result set, so there is no row to insert any more

The second problem is you actively demand that if certain supplied parameters are null, then no data shall be returned:

```
WHERE ... AND @maritalStatusDesc Is Not Null
```

If you set your maritalsStatusDesc parameter to null that's it - game over for any hope of ever getting anything out of this query; it will never return a row because your where clause insists that the query only returns rows when the parameter is not null..

---

As to what to do about it?

Use an ORM like Entity Framework or nHibernate; it makes this stuff a breeze. You work with objects, you assign a marital status and it works. If it's not assigned, EF will work out all the null stuff for you

If you insist on carrying on this way that you are currently, remove that WHERE clause and convert all your INNER joins to LEFT OUTER instead. Now, when you do this, and you send a null data the join will fail so you won't get any data out of maritalstatus table (the ID column for that row will be null, so hopefully your main column is nullable) but it does at least mean the result set will still have a row that can be inserted

Personally, **I wouldn't try to do it all in one statement**. If you want to know the ID for a status of "married", look it up in code first, so you have the ID and can then insert it. Use two SQL statements; one is `SELECT ID FROM MaritalStatus WHERE MaritalStatusDesc = @msd` and the other is `INSERT INTO ... VALUES @msd_id`, @msg_id being the ID you looked up before you ran the insert statement

You can make your life easier by having a helper class that takes string descriptions and returns IDs (or returns DBNull.Value) so the lookups are done as part of the parameter adding when youre getting ready to run the insert:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@maritalStatusId", IDLookupHelper.GetIDForMaritalStatusDesc(msdTextBox.Text)));
```

Here's what a code for that might look like:

```
public object GetIDForMaritalStatusDesc(string msd){
  if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(msd))
    return DBNull.Value;
  using(SqlCommand sq = new SqlCommand(
    "connstr here", 
    "SELECT ID FROM MaritalStatusWHERE Desc = @msd"
  );){
    sq.Parameters.AddWithValue("@msd", msd); //note: google "can we stop using addwithvalue already"

    try{ 
      return sq.ExecuteScalar();
    } catch {
      return DBNull.Value
    }
  }
}
```

This is a stub; you can expand it. It's just to give you an idea. Please do consider using an ORM for this because you'll be able to move away from wasting your life writing boring repetitive data access code - an ORM will do a better, faster job and make your work life more interesting